# Ion-datetime, when pass value to ‘max’ date, not see monthes list till scroll

Tags: ionic2, maxdate

I user ion-datetime plugin.
All worked fine, till I tried to pass value to 'max' param.
I limit the date picker to 18 years ago.
The result is that when user open the datepicker, he see only years and days lists, if he want to select month - he need to 'pull' the month-list by scrolling.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" [(ngModel)]="user.dob" [formControl]="birthdate" [max]="maxDob"></ion-datetime>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
export class SignUpPage {
   maxDob: string;
   signUpProfileForm: FormGroup;
   birthdate: AbstractControl;


   constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {  }

   ngOnInit() {
      var self = this;
      self.signUpProfileForm= self.fb.group({
        'birthdate': [],
      });

      self.maxDob =  new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 18)).toISOString();

  }

}
```

P.S. if you are user with at list 1500 reputation, I will be happy if you will create new tag - "ion-datetime".

Answer (score 0):

make Use of moment

```
export class Abc{

today:any;
mDate:any;

this.today =  moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

let maxDate=  new Date((new Date().getFullYear() - 18),new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate());
       this.mDate=moment(maxDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

In HTML :

```
 <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MMM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="todo.date" max = "{{today}}" min="{{mDate}}"></ion-datetime>
```

Comment: In HTML:   <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MMM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="todo.date"max = "{{today}}" min="{{mDate}}"></ion-datetime>